# injectedJavaScript is not working in Webview of react native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, webview

I am not able to inject this simple js code into react-native webview.

[I referred this link also but no solution provided here.](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11581)

[Then I found this one which works for html props but not uri.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41260270/updating-webview-javascript-in-react-native)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  WebView
} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component<{}> {

  injectjs(){

    let jsCode = 'alert(hello)';
    return jsCode;
  }

  render() {
    return <WebView 
    javaScriptEnabled={true}
    injectedJavaScript={this.injectjs()} 
    source={{uri:"https://www.google.com"}} style={{ marginTop: 20 }} />;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Add `onMessage` method does work.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  WebView
} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component<{}> {
  render() {
    return 
      <WebView 
        javaScriptEnabled={true}
        injectedJavaScript={'alert("hello")'} 
        source={{uri:"https://www.google.com"}} style={{ marginTop: 20 }}
        onMessage={(event) => {
          console.log('event: ', event)
        }}
      />;
  }
}
```

Comment: Adding the empty `onMessage` with dummy function works like a charm.

Comment: Nice, worked for me too! Also, worth noticing, I was passing it as `injectedJavascript` instead of `injectedJavaScript` with the capital S, so beware of this silly mistake!

Answer (score 8):

Well, you have more than one issue here.  First one is your web view needs to be wrapped in a containing View component with flex: 1.  Second, injectedJavascript only accepts a string - not a function.  Third, it seems you are attempting to use hello as a variable without defining it, or if it is a string than your syntax needs to be something like this: injectedJavascript={'alert("hello")'}.  Furthermore, injectedJavascript is already fired when the view loads so you are all good there if that's what you are intending to do.  You can inject javascript when the web view starts loading though, using a combination of the props, onLoadStart and injectJavascript, but the implementation is quite different, so that's a different question.  Try this code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  WebView
} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {

  render() {
    let yourAlert = 'alert("hello")'
    return (
     <View style={{flex: 1}}>
       <WebView
        javaScriptEnabled={true}
        domStorageEnabled={true}
        injectedJavaScript={yourAlert}
        source={{ uri: "https://www.google.com" }} style={{ marginTop: 20  }} />
    </View>
   )
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to add a async function that awaits for token and return as string to  injectedJavaScript? I cant seems to figure it out. Appricate your help

Answer (score 7):

You need to add onMessage props.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this issue as well, and I was able to get it to work by setting mixedContentMode:

**mixedContentMode={'compatibility'}**

see below where props.url = {uri:'https://google.com'} quick test javascript pastes "look at me, I'm injecting" into the search box.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, StyleSheet, Text, View, ScrollView, WebView } from 'react-native';

export class WebViewController extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        const url = this.props.url;
        console.log(`v:1`);
        console.log(`url info: ${JSON.stringify(url)}`);
        console.log(`javascript: ${Constants.javascript.injection}`);
        return (
            <View style={styles.root}>
                <WebView
                    source={url}
                    injectedJavaScript={Constants.javascript.injection}
                    mixedContentMode={'compatibility'}
                    javaScriptEnabled={true}
                    style={styles.webview}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    root: {
        flex:1,
        alignSelf: 'stretch',
    },
    webview: {
        flex:1,
        alignSelf: 'stretch',
    },
})

const Constants = {
    javascript: {
        injection: `
            Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('input')).forEach((item) => {
                if(item.type == "search") {
                    item.value = "look at me, I'm injecting";
                }
            })
        `
    }
}
```

I expect the problem is when your adding your html directly and injecting javascript the webview considers the injection as javascript from the same origin.  Unlike when you load a page through a url, where your javascript is foreign and is considered outside of the origin by the default value of mixedContentMode which is 'never'

see: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html#mixedcontentmode

mixedContentMode
Specifies the mixed content mode. i.e WebView will allow a secure origin to load content from any other origin.

Possible values for mixedContentMode are:

'never' (default) - WebView will not allow a secure origin to load content from an insecure origin.
'always' - WebView will allow a secure origin to load content from any other origin, even if that origin is insecure.
'compatibility' - WebView will attempt to be compatible with the approach of a modern web browser with regard to mixed content.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Guide.md#the-injectjavascript-method

```
follow this link 

The injectJavaScript method

While convenient, the downside to the previously mentioned 
injectedJavaScript prop is that it only runs once. That's why we 
also expose a method on the webview ref called injectJavaScript 
(note the slightly different name!).
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a empty ref & onMessage fixed this for me:

```
onMessage={(event) => {}}
ref={() => {}}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone struggling with this in 2021, what I ended up having to do (pretty dirty solution but it worked), was to poll for the necessary dependencies I was injecting into the `window` object via `injectedJavaScriptBeforeContentLoaded`, and only running the rest of my code when they became available.

My solution ended up looking something like this:

```
function app () {
    // Continue to re-call self until frame data is available
    if (typeof window._rendererFrameData === 'undefined') {
        setTimeout(app, 250);
        return;
    }

    // Passed in from RN
    var size = window._rendererSize;
    var pixelSize = window._rendererPixelSize;

    // Picture data
    var frames = [];
    window._rendererFrameData.forEach(function(frameString) {
        frames.push(frameString.split(''));
    });
    var frameIndex = 0;

    var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
    canvas.setAttribute('width', size * pixelSize + 2);
    canvas.setAttribute('height', size * pixelSize + 2);
    document.body.setAttribute('width', size * pixelSize + 2);
    document.body.setAttribute('height', size * pixelSize + 2);
    

    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    
    // ... rest of renderer logic
}

app();
```

Note the if statement w/ `setTimeout` and return at the start. Basically it checks if my injected data is undefined, then queues the function to re-run in 250 milliseconds and bails out. This continues until the data is available.

Feels like a seriously bad case of band-aid solution, but it works for my app!